# What approach should I use in mysql database designing that includes more than billion of rows to find particular value using minimum of time?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, indexing

I have a Django project where I have to solve the following task: client paste the phone number to the search field and application returns full address. If there is no requested address in database, it should be added to another database table of unknown numbers. So, when admin uploads the list of number-address pairs, application should check if everey number exists in database table of unknown numbers. And if exists - it should be removed. This database after some time will contain more than billion rows. My approach is to create two database tables: first - the main table with two columns: "number" and "address". For the column "number" I provide indexation for the faster searching for address. And second one - table with unknown numbers where will be single column "number" which also should be indexed. So, asking for help of experts: do I think right? Or what approach should be the best to solve this task?

I can not ask you for deep answer, I just need to which direction I should move on.

Thank you very much. I will be happy for any kind of help (comments, links etc).

Comment: The idea of SO is to ask quite concrete questions and also expect explicit answers. And you should provide a shorter title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`number` should be the `PRIMARY KEY` in each of your tables.  This will make "billion rows" not-a-problem.

Two somewhat simple SQL statements can perform the maintenance you describe very rapidly.